# Linux AMD setup freezes randomly without any kernel errors

Tags: drivers, kernel, 19.04

This thing has never worked properly and it's fairly new (I built it on Friday). My specs are:

- AMD Ryzen 5 2600
- Sapphire Radeon RX 590
- G.SKILL 16GB 3000MHz Aegis CL16 (2x8GB)
- MSI B450M Mortar

After about 3-5 hours of casual usage my computer freezes. The EZ Debug LED indicates a CPU error. I can't find any related logs in the kernel messages. I'm running Kubuntu 19.04, kernel 5.0.0-13-generic.

Comment: As usual there can be a million reasons for that happening, but try to disable "Automatic C-State Management" in the BIOS if you have that option. It helped me with a similar problem on a Ryzen system.

Comment: @Sebastian the problem was caused by a WiFi card. Removing it solved the problem.